# Iteratively naming columns in a pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I feel like this should be easy but I couldn't find a solution.

The current column names are just: 0,1,2,3,4,5.

And I want to rename them to: bid_1, bidsize_1, bid_2, bidsize_2, bid_3, bidsize_3.

I've tried `['bid_' + str(i) for i in range(1,4)] + ['bidsize_' + str(i) for i in range(1,4)]` and got `['bid_1', 'bid_2', 'bid_3', 'bidsize_1', 'bidsize_2', 'bidsize_3']`. But the ordering is not what I wanted.

Comment: what are the original column names? what are the final column names? Try and make your question clearer.

Comment: Thanks! just edited the question:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this-

```py
df.columns = [s+str(i+1) for i in range(len(df.columns)//2) for s in ['bid_', 'bidsize_']]
```

```
['bid_1',
 'bidsize_1',
 'bid_2',
 'bidsize_2',
 'bid_3',
 'bidsize_3']
```

Comment: much simpler solution.

Comment: Thanks! But it might break if the columns are not even but assuming what OP needs, this should suffice.

Comment: @sammywemmy Thanks for your answer though:) I read through it and it was super helpful as well.